# When looping through objects with criteria, displays empty bullets when not matched

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I'm sure this is a pretty basic question but I want to display a list of Symptoms matching a specific SymptomID. I have the following code which checks if the specific symptom is of a specific type but when the type is not correct, the code still outputs a blank bullet in its place.

```
<h1>Symptoms</h1>
<h2> {{symptomtypes[0].Description}}</h2>
<li *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms">
    <p *ngIf="(symptom.SymptomTypeID == 1)"> {{symptom.Description}}</p>
</li>
<h2> {{symptomtypes[1].Description}}</h2>
<li *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms">
    <p *ngIf="(symptom.SymptomTypeID == 2)"> {{symptom.Description}}</p>
</li>
<h2> {{symptomtypes[2].Description}}</h2>
<li *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms">
    <p *ngIf="(symptom.SymptomTypeID == 3)"> {{symptom.Description}}</p>
</li>
```

I expect the list to output as follows: 
**Symptom Type 1**

- Symptom Type 1
- Symptom Type 1
- Symptom Type 1

   
  **Symptom Type 2**
- Symptom Type 2
- Symptom Type 2
- Symptom Type 2

   
  **Symptom Type 3**
- Symptom Type 3
- Symptom Type 3
- Symptom Type 3

   
  But instead I get something like: 
  **Symptom Type 1**
- Blank
- Blank
- Symptom Type 1

   
  **Symptom Type 2**
- Symptom Type 2
- Blank
- Symptom Type 2

   
  **Symptom Type 3**
- Symptom Type 3
- Blank
- Blank

Comment: I would suggest [using `reduce` to group your array into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40774697/215552) instead of using indexes like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the solution you are looking for is.

```
<h1>Symptoms</h1>
<h2> Symptom Type 1</h2>
<div *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms">
  <li *ngIf="(symptom.SymptomTypeID == 1)&& (symptom.Description)">
    {{symptom.Description}}
  </li>
</div>
<h2> Symptom Type 2</h2>
<div *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms">
  <li *ngIf="(symptom.SymptomTypeID == 2)&& (symptom.Description)">
    {{symptom.Description}}
  </li>
</div>
<h2> Symptom Type 3</h2>
<div *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms">
  <li *ngIf="(symptom.SymptomTypeID == 3) && (symptom.Description)">
    {{symptom.Description}}
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't the ideal way to display values, but for this particular case.
I guess the solution you are looking for is.

```
<h2> {{symptomtypes[2].Description}}</h2>
<li *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms">
    <p *ngIf="(symptom.SymptomTypeID == 3) && symptom.Description"> {{symptom.Description}}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that every iteration of `*ngFor` the html element on which you have applied `*ngFor` is created (see [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)). Because of that you have the empty entries.

In your case I would suggest you to use a [pipe](https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe) to filter your array.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filterSymptom' })
export class FilterSymptomPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(symptoms: Symptom[], id: number) {
        return symptoms.filter(s => s.SymptomTypeID  === id);
    }
}
```

And in your html:

```
<li *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms | filterSymptom: 3">
    <p"> {{symptom.Description}}</p>
</li>
```

And to improve your code generally I would suggest you to do something like following:

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let symptomtype of symptomtypes; let index=index;">
    <h2> {{symptomtype.Description}}</h2>
    <li *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms | filterSymptom: index + 1]">
        <p"> {{symptom.Description}}</p>
    </li>
</ng-template>
```

With this way you prevent the usage of hard coded indexes.